# Unique-Query function not pulling all Unique Rows

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

So I've been searching for days.  I am running a spreadsheet to track game stats for a video game League.  I need to break the players down into their specific roles, and show their stats for only the weeks they played those roles.

Got the stats working but having a problem pulling all the players' names.  I was using a UNIQUE(QUERY) function to pull the names from each week's games, but I noticed that not all the players were being pulled even if they matched the criteria.  What did I do wrong?

Here's a copy of the spreadsheet for you all to comment on: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18C-edA8uvyVLnozBLqOhOba4_ukzyhtXKFIno-XXsKU/edit?usp=sharing

Formula in question is most easily seen on the "THE ADCs" tab, E11.

The specific Formula Array is as follows:

=UNIQUE(QUERY({Week1_Stats!$B4:$AH,Week2_Stats!$B4:$AH,Week3_Stats!$B4:$AH,Week4_Stats!$B4:$AH,Week5_Stats!$B4:$AH,Week6_Stats!$B4:$AH,Week7_Stats!$B4:$AH,Week8_Stats!$B4:$AH,Week9_Stats!$B4:$AH,Week10_Stats!$B4:$AH},"Select Col2 Where Col3 ='ADC' and Col5 > .5 Order by Col5 Desc Limit 10"))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a number of problems in your formula. First, you've used commas to separate your array of ranges for `QUERY` to process; but commas signify placing an element *to the right of the previous element*. You need semicolons to stack those ranges one above the other*.

You're also asking `QUERY` to `LIMIT` results *before* `UNIQUE` is applied. This would leave you with 10 items, some of which may be repeats, which are *then* reduced to unique items; whereas I assume you want the *final list of unique entries* to be 10.

You also need to add `WHERE Col2 Is Not Null` to your `QUERY` conditions, because a blank entry counts as `UNIQUE` unless ruled out.

Try the following in place of your present formula in `'THE ADCs'!E11` and see if it produces the result you were expecting:

`=ArrayFormula(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(UNIQUE(QUERY({Week1_Stats!$B4:$AH;Week2_Stats!$B4:$AH;Week3_Stats!$B4:$AH;Week4_Stats!$B4:$AH;Week5_Stats!$B4:$AH;Week6_Stats!$B4:$AH;Week7_Stats!$B4:$AH;Week8_Stats!$B4:$AH;Week9_Stats!$B4:$AH;Week10_Stats!$B4:$AH},"Select Col2 Where Col2 Is Not Null and Col3 ='ADC' and Col5 > 0.5 Order by Col5 Desc")),10,1))`

Comment: You are amazing!  There's still a ton I am learning, so I didn't even know about the semicolons.  

The formula adjustment you gave worked like a charm <3 thank you so much!!!

Comment: Glad to hear it. Given that everything is working as expected, please take a moment to mark my reply post as "Best Answer". This alerts the rest of the volunteer contributor community that an answer has already been provided, which helps us all be more efficient. And it allows future site visitors with similar issues to more quickly find relevant answers. Thanks.